# As a system integrator, what is the recommended set of tests to run on each build?

Tags: magento2, testing

To clarify, by **"System Integrator"** I mean, **"I am working on a full Magento project, not just a module"**

I am currently working with Travis and already am using composer to import all custom extensions (some private, some public).

At the time, I am dealing with 2 issues:

1. Magento2 tests simply break here and there
2. The provided tests take WAAAAAY to long to run

To fix (1) I am simply customizing `phpunit.xml.dist` to skip the broken tests. No big deal.

To fix (2) I am attempting to do the following:

- No unit tests (both PHP and JS). Each module should have their own unit tests run in their independent repositories, the project should only use stable well-tested modules
- Limit all static tests to only run on theme and local customizations via whitelists

By doing that, main static tests run in 2 min 10 sec, JS static tests run in 1 min 50 sec but still have integration and functional tests run for over an hour.

I am wondering if there is value in running all integration and functional tests or if there are some core tests that safely be skipped for a faster build.

Like, I am already skipping `CodeGeneratorTest.php` because it breaks out of the box, but it is pretty clear to me that there isn't really much value in testing the `CodeGenerationEngine` as I am obviously not messing around changing that (famous last words), any other candidates?

There is really no way of telling what is actually being tested in the whole testsuite without digging really deep in the engine .

**UDPATE**: we switched to completely disabling functional tests at the moment and are only running integration tests when a change to composer dependencies is detected. Pretty happy with the results so far. Still, skipping acceptance tests without really knowing what they test makes me a little nervous.